# React - when do I need to call ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode

Tags: reactjs

If I render a component into a domNode and then again render another component into the same domNode my understanding is that this is a replace operation rather than an append. The first component will be removed from the dom and from the React Tree in the Virtual representation of the DOM. Therefore I don't need to specifically call ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode to clean up the first component.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. According to the [ReactDOM docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html), on `ReactDOM.render()`:

> In the future, it may be possible to insert a component to an existing DOM node without overwriting the existing children.

This means that it is not even currently possible to append using `ReactDOM.render()` - components always get destroyed and replaced.

Generally it is better to avoid the `ReactDOM` module unless completely necessary. For most React apps, you'll find it is only used to render just the top level wrapper component to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for this response. This article https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html suggests that not calling `unmountComponentAtNode` will result in memory leaks. Is this article just old and outdated?